# Xcode slow build time in editor

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I'm editing a single file in Xcode, it takes several seconds to any kind of syntax error to show up. Sometimes errors don't even show up until I go to the menu and build manually. It makes development awfully slow as I have to constantly wait to check if I miswrote something...

I don't think it's because of the machine, though its a Macbook Air, but I do Android development on this machine too, and Android Studio can show me syntax errors just fine.

Is there any way to make this part faster? Or I need a better machine?

Comment: Open Activity Monitor to check if Xcode is using all the available CPU resources, that will indicate if your machine is not capable of running it properly.

Comment: An usual problem with big modules that have a lot of dependencies between files, especially with generics. If you have a big codebase, consider splitting it to separate modules. Every module can then compile independently and also helps with your project organization and overall architecture.

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/11/how-to-make-swift-compile-faster

Comment: @vikingosegundo That article is pretty much outdated. Avoiding ternaries, nil-coalescing and type inferring is not a good solution. Thinking about dependencies between files, using `private` when needed and splitting project to smaller modules is the real solution. You can improve compilation time of methods but with many file dependencies the real problem is that many files have to be compiled multiple times.

Comment: @Sulthan, if compiling a swift file takes hours with type inference and just seconds with explicit typing, I happily type.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I am working on large project codebases, type inferring everything and I still have fast build times on the cheapest Macbook Air. It's the architecture, not small optimizations. However, I do agree that Xcode 10 helped a lot.

Comment: @Sulthan good for you that you work on large code bases — as I do. I know of the importance of proper architecting the code and modularising it. But I guess OP can also use help on a simpler level.